# How do I remove a language in language bar that isn't in my settings in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language, language-bar

I have been playing a game that involves pushing what is apparently the keyboard shortcut for changing my keyboard language. This changes the mapping of the keys to something totally different and renders several games unplayable.

I finally figured out what was happening. I have German keyboard option in the language bar in the bottom right. I don't speak German, never have, and have no idea why it's even on there.

I tried to remove it from the language settings but it doesn't even seem to be an option, yet it's showing up in the bar.

How do I remove the other language so that I can stop running into this language toggling problem?

**Here is the language bar with the German keyboard option:**

[image]

**Here are my language options, without the German language in it:**

[image]
[image]